# How can I see my single longest answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've answered a lot of questions, hence it would not be comfortable to check each one separately. Recently, I answered a question with a long explanation including code. It reminded me of my longest answer, and hence I am here asking this question. I couldn't find any other posts featuring this exact question, so I decided to ask this myself.

Is there a way to view my single longest answer that I've posted on Stack Overflow?

Comment: you could search through your posts by using filter `user:me` if you were to remember the context

Comment: @SurajRao although, that is uncomfortable to check each answer on which one is the longest, I have posted about 50 answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461291/is-it-safe-to-change-web-server-root-directory-to-owners-rootwww-data-with-775/60466368#60466368 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747714/phpmyadmin-is-available-on-all-apache-domains/59750453#59750453?

Comment: @SamuelLiew, umm.. Thats quick research, I am pretty thankful for that LOL. Maybe thats it. I may close this question, but I was expecting like an easy way to view it each time I post long answers, with updated results. Is that possible? If not, I will close this. I am expecting like a query place in stack exchange, where you can check this updated.

Comment: You must remember some text from the answer? Something like `user:me is:answer created:1m.. [tag-name] keywords` will give all your answers from last 1 month with the tag `tag-name` includes the `keyword`

Comment: @adiga that might help.

Comment: Check this for advanced searching https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @SamuelLiew you can straight away tell me close it or delete it if it is not possible.

Comment: @adiga, that helps me in everything else :D Thanks! other than this.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, thanks for that. I will do the rest of it. Also, its enough for now. In future, just so that I don't have to struggle, is there a way I can view updated results from like a query on? Even if it includes the other sites, like Ask Ubuntu, I don't mind. is there a way I can view my longest answer on stackexchange network, or stackoverflow?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana assuming you are comfortable with SQL, [data.SE] is your friend here as long as you accept that the data is not real time (updated weekly).  But you should be able to put together whatever queries you like

Comment: [Here is something that can give you a start](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1265325?UserId=3689450). It's checking, not just answers but you can add what you need there.

Comment: @VLAZ, post it as an answer so I can accept :D That solved my issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1265325) to find your longest posts. Here is what I used:

```sql
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId:int##;

SELECT TOP 3 Id [Post Link], LEN(Body), Body
FROM posts
WHERE OwnerUserId = @UserId
ORDER BY LEN(Body) DESC
```

The `DECLARE` is so it can take a user ID. You can supply your own or any other user's just next to the **Run Query** button.

From there it selects the top 3 posts - questions or answers alike, ordered by post length where the poster was the user ID supplied. `Id [Post Link]` will automatically give you a link to the post ([see **Magic Columns** section here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/introducing-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-aka-sede)).

If you start composing a query, you'd be able to see the table schema, so you can add more information if you need it or modify the query. For example, if you want questions or answers only, you can use the `PostTypeId` column where `1` is a question and `2` is an answer. You can further do joins or different aggregation or breakdown of the data, if needed.

[See the SEDE tutorial here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

There are two things to be aware of:

- The data is not real-time. It's updated every week on Sunday, so on Monday it is going to be the most up-to-date.
- You will not be able to query for deleted posts. Those reside in the `PostsWithDeleted` table, however only some of the data is publicly available, other gets removed. The removed data includes the `OwnerUserId` (who posted it) as well as the `Body` column, so you will not be able to find neither the longest deleted post, nor even your own deleted posts (or any particular user's).