# Why are articles a part of collectives?

Tags: discussion, collectives, articles

I am trying to understand what is the purpose of articles.

This feature was [announced in 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/12/how-we-built-it-articles-feature-stack-overflow-teams/) and [released in 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/03/find-knowledge-faster-new-articles-features/) for teams. And currently articles is a part of collectives feature.

The articles can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aarticle) (currently just 3) and there are already [topics on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/articles) about articles (namely [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409281/1997232) which leads me to posting this question). Two of them are `[how-to guide]` and can be *easily* converter to Q&A format. And the one of `[announcement]` type feel very off-topic to me (like a sort of advertisement or promotion).

I am trying to put things together and understand reasons of appearing articles in collectives which are not private teams at all. Private teams can ignore SO standards and articles feels to me like a *blog* build into teams.

### What is the purpose of articles? Why they are needed for collectives specifically?

From the first blog the purpose of articles for teams is this:

> Articles allows for the creation and sharing of **long-form content** within Teams. While we believe that questions and answers are still the best mechanism when soliciting “in the moment” knowledge, Articles allow users to share information with fellow team members **proactively and in much greater detail**. Sometimes, **the narrative** of how and why decisions were made adds another layer of understanding to the creation and maintenance of software. And having your longer form content in the same place as your Q&A means less context switching

Can someone explain to me how the article is different from the long answer or multiple answers? What is proactively? Answering questions nobody will ask? Why narrative of answers is not what narrative of articles is? And  why `[announcement]`, `[policy]` and what else article types are allowed for articles while questions will be closed as off-topic?

Comment: Difference: There is no question. That alone changes the scope and the approach. Things that simple wouldn't work as answers to questions, or where the question itself wouldn't work in our Q&A model (e.g. because it would be closed as "needs focus", etc). Also, articles can only be written by Trusted Members of the collective.

Comment: _"What is proactively? Answering questions nobody will ask?"_: No, it means providing the content without waiting for a question to be asked.

Comment: @yivi "There is no question." Isn't there always an implicit question in the way that I could create a question that would ask for exactly what is stated in a piece of content. For example: "What is the newest thing you are excited about and want to tell me?"

Comment: @Trilarion Not really. You could always construe some kind of question for which an article could work as some kind of answer, but that does not mean there is an "implicit question". Also, an "implicit imaginary question" is not the same as an "explicit, real question by a real Stack Overflow user".

Comment: @yivi Yes, it's not the same, but saying there is no question doesn't sound fair either. Articles still have a topic and are centered around it. It's not like they are supposed to be shopping lists (or are they?).

Comment: @Trilarion It's not "fair". It's simply true. There is no question An article is not an answer. They have "topics" (one or more), but they are not answers to questions. Not every statement is an answer, even if it can be used as an answer to an hypothetical question.

Comment: @yivi The title is basically what used to be the question and I just looked at them and I can easily make a question out of every title. So for me, they are somewhat close to questions, for you they are more different.

Comment: Another, maybe more interesting question, might be if articles could be useful outside of collectives. Are articles maybe something we would like to have in general? I'm kind of undecided because I think that Q&A already covers quite a lot of territory and longer, more broad stuff that is also high quality may be a hard job to create.

Answer (score 7):

> Can someone explain to me how the article is different from the long answer or multiple answers

TL;DR

The difference between an Article and an Answer is that an Answer answers a Question.

---

The point is not that Articles are answering questions that nobody will ask. The point is that they are providing information in the form of an exposition rather than as a question and answer(s).

One of the big problems with Stack Overflow as a knowledge resource is many things are difficult to teach in Q&A format. Consider for example the syntax of a programming language:

- Do we want a Q&A for each operator, each statement, each kind of type, and so on?  That's not a good approach teaching.
- Do we want a Q that covers the entire syntax? That's too broad.
- Do we want a Q which asks for links to other Q's about the above? Wouldn't survive.
- Do we want Questions with multiple Answers competing for the reader's attention (and votes)? No. It's too messy. And there are too many incorrect, inaccurate or out-of-date answers (And down-voting is NOT effective in sorting them out).

---

Properly curated and organized Articles are *potentially* a better way. Let's assume the experts in a collective are basically on the same page about what should be in Articles and how to organize them... for their collective. What we would hope to get is:

- Better written articles, written by (ideally) people with both good writing skills and good domain knowledge.
- Better organized content.
- Less duplication.
- Less out-of-date, inaccurate and/or plain wrong content.
- A process for the experts to come to a consensus.

Will it work out? We shall see!

---

> What is the purpose of articles?

See above.

> Why they are needed for collectives specifically?

They are needed for Stack Overflow in general (This, to me, is obvious).

The Documentation project was an attempt to provide this kind of thing. It failed because it ignored the need for experts, and it didn't provide a good way to moderate the content. It was just one huge free-for-all... and resulted in one giant disorganized mess of (largely) low quality content.

With Collectives, there is (IMO) a better chance of success because:

- It is not a free for all. Only the experts get to write articles, and they get to decide what is *worth* writing about.
- They are starting with just two collectives, so that there is an opportunity for lessons to be learned in terms of how a collective should regulate themselves, and what tools they need to do it.

Once again, we shall see if it works.

Comment: What about short articles? What about riduculously long ones? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/1997232) is the longest answer of Jon Skeet (using query from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399581/1997232)) and his answers are among the best, so I doubt we *need* long posts here. Write a book, post in blog and just refer to it here.

Comment: That's just a curation issue.  If people aren't happy with long articles, there will be feedback ... and hopefully the curators will adjust them.

Comment: @Sinatr That answer does not have a lot of content: It is long just because it contains a lot of Java code that does one thing. It doesn't explain a lot, it explains one thing. A better example is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php). That isn't QA. That is an article forced into a QA format.

Comment: Another interesting thing about the PHP article found by MegaIng is that it has been closed and reopened twice, and there have been 5 further attempts to close by voting ... that have failed. So there clearly is a level of unhappines with questions like that; i.e. trying to shoe-horn an article into Q&A format. Even though it is Community Wiki

Comment: @MegaIng "That isn't QA. That is an article forced into a QA format." It isn't Q&A but I'm not sure that it is an article either. To me it looks like a link list, basically something like the awesome lists on Github because search technology alone is not sufficient to realize that these linked Q&A belong together. But there is little original content beyond the links.

Comment: @Trilarion The questions seen alone maybe. But together with all the answers, it does look like an article to me.

Comment: @Megalng That's not an article, that's a reference manual. It's not formatted and intended to be read top to bottom, it's meant to be searched and hyperlinked into.

Comment: *"Consider for example the syntax of a programming language"*, so basically a chapter of a textbook. I don't quite see how it'll work, for starters the UI doesn't fit well and I'm not sure what votes are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2):

From [Beta release of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow):

> Articles:
> Collectives on Stack Overflow adds the ability to create , **longer form content** that lives on the collective page. We first introduced this feature within our Teams product last year, and we have seen strong adoption and usage. Articles give Recognized Members the opportunity to **provide deeper knowledge and insights through how-to-guides, knowledge articles, or announcements**.

and

> We’ve also learned that **organizations** who are active on Stack Overflow have a **strong appetite to add their specific knowledge**. They want to have **deeper interactions and provide a better experience to their current and potential users**. Currently, they **can’t do that with any of our products**.

and from [Town hall - Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408734/town-hall-collectives-on-stack-overflow/408764#408764):

> The scope of an article should be broader than a regular Q&A. We envision it to be the content piece that is **in between Q&A (specific problem, specific solution) and documentation (full description on how something works)**. An example would be a how-to guide on how to get started on a specific technology.

Emphasizes added by me.

To summarize all this:

Articles are thought to be broader and longer than regular Q&A providing deeper knowledge and insights in form of guides, knowledge resources and announcements that give **organizations** (and only them) that are currently craving to add their specific knowledge in forms of announcements or guides or longer, deeper and broader knowledge articles a way to directly interact with their users/customers on SO, which they couldn't do with the regular Q&A so far. Clear?

It's not just for promoting knowledge (then articles would just exist outside of Collectives), **it's for promoting only specific knowledge from organizations**! A bit of a broadcasting/marketing channel, but with some voting on top.

Basically there is much more leeway about the content (although they also still have to be [somewhat ontopic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408945/1536976)) and announcements for example are explicitly included. However, so far there are only a few and the length is also not much more than the average Q&A, but maybe this will change in the future.

It's too early to judge them really, but from the three examples my impression is that they are a bit more on the advertising side of knowledge transfer, and then it's maybe good that they are clearly marked as part of collectives.

Independently of this it might be a good idea to have articles available everywhere but then hopefully also with adapted rules like focused only on content and editable by everyone.

Comment: Writing articles is going to be difficult, just as difficult as writing a blog or wiki documentation. I struggle myself with the length of wiki articles for example. If you cram too much in the same article, it becomes harder to find the truth inside it. If you spread it out too much over smaller articles you run into fragmentation and duplication. Finding that sweet spot is a lot of work and you really have to want to get it right, revisiting the text over and over. In my opinion it is going to take a *long* time before articles will start to make sense, if ever.

Comment: @Gimby One could start with asking for what people would actually like to have guides on or one could take big topics (like machine learning) and try to break them down into bits and then use the small bits (loss functions for example) as a topic for a guide. A lot of links between articles could then make the whole thing valuable. (But then it would be like Wikipedia.)

Comment: That would be documentation. I am right now not going to make the assumption that articles are going to be used that way. In a month or six I will revisit that and see in which direction the collectives pushed them. The term "article" is very broad after all, it in no way implies the sharing of technical knowledge. It can just as easily be product marketing.

Comment: @Gimby It's a good idea to wait for say at least 20 articles and then revisit the discussions around them, but my impression was that articles are thought to be part of the knowledge content family on SO. Voting doesn't really make sense on product marketing.

Answer (score 1):

> long-form content

Not so much. At least not in the [first 3 articles](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aarticle). They are listed as "1 min read", and indeed they are that size. I expected Articles to be somewhat of a hybrid between a comprehensive answer to an unasked question and full documentation. I also expected the first few Articles to be planned in advance and far more detailed & polished from the <s>Borg</s> Google Collective.

But I do think there is a real use for Articles, despite my concerns about the initial implementation. On [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com), some of the regulars have recognized the need. The problem is implementation. You can write a made-up Question as a vehicle to create a place to put useful information to answer very frequently asked (often duplicate or near-duplicate) questions, and the top DIY user [tried that a couple of years ago](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul). The problem is that as an ordinary question it very quickly fades from view, and in fact it becomes hard to actually find it when you want to refer to it, unless you saved the post ID.

My main point though is that really good Articles should not be in any way tied to a particular group of people based on occupation, affiliation, members of the Borg Collective, etc. **A good Article is a good Article. Period.** Requiring a moderately high Reputation/Badge/etc. is reasonable. But there is no reason a self-taught non-professional programmer can't write an Article that is as **useful** as one from the top people at Google/Microsoft/AWS/etc. The collaborative nature of Stack Overflow should help even more - the experts (because they work for the companies that created the language/system/environment/etc.) can help fine-tune information from the experts (from "in the trenches" daily use of the language/system/environment/etc.). It really shouldn't matter who starts the Article - **the results, as judged by the community, are what matters**.

Comment: "...in fact it becomes hard to actually find it..." If a top quality article is hard to find, then imagine how bad ordinary articles would be to find. This hints that a knowledge library like StackExchanges should invest much effort into retrieving information. Just creating a new category so stuff is easier to find will work for like one year maybe and then one would face the same problem, but then with two buckets to search in instead of one.

Comment: One of the new things at [Codidact](https://codidact.com) is to have categories of content that are not necessarily standard Q&A. Every site gets a regular Q&A and Meta. But others have some Q without A (e.g., for Code Golf Sandbox instead of having it as one Q with a million A) or "Blogs" aka "Articles" etc. By having a separate top-level category (that's separate from Tags) the content is easily discoverable.

Comment: Re *"some Q without A"*: What is it then? A document? A wiki page? A monolith page expected to start with a question or some meta content about the expected content? Something else?

Comment: It can be a document - "Article", "Blog", whatever. Or it can be a Wiki, though I think that would be more based on a true linking between pages which isn't quite there yet (could be done manually, of course, but real tools/structure would make a big difference). Could be a monolith starting with a hypothetical question. As with the Articles here, it could be whatever the community wants - the differences are (a) discoverability (which actually it looks like Collectives has, though I'm still trying to understand it all) and "open to anyone to write, not just a special group".

Comment: Sounds good to me. But on the one hand categories only sound like additional meta tags and it's not clear how they improve discoverability if there are lots of documents in each category or what other advantage they might have. On the other hand there might be problems like if there is overlap in scope, where to put some piece of content or if it's possible that a piece of content in one category be a duplicate target of another. It surely adds a bit of complexity. But why not, I'd like to try it out but I would not expect miracles and search must be improved in any case.

Comment: @Trilarion The idea (in my mind) is that Categories are like the current "Main" vs. "Meta" - separate groups of "stuff", and the "stuff" can then be either traditional Q&A or Articles or Wiki or some other yet-to-be-determined format. But it does get complicated to do it right - in particular, search (as you mentioned) must be improved - specifically to handle search across all Categories at one time *when desired*. A search for "username" might mean one thing in Main - how to handle authentication in a particular system - vs. Meta - "how do I merge my two usernames". Etc.